# How do I copy an array returned by a function into another array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm trying to return an array populated inside a function to another array, so I can use the values inside the array for a slideshow.

My code is :

```
       var flag = 0
    var slideimages = new Array()
    slideimages = readfile()

    function readfile(){
    //read data into array x
    flag =1
    return x
    }

    if(flag == 1){
    //execute slideshow functions
    }

    //slideshow functions definitions (for timeout n picture index etc)
    //using slideimages[index] to choose pic
```

Could anyone help me out here?

My slideshow isn't running, and I'm guessing it's because the values aren't getting copied into the slideimages[]

edit:

Here is my code:

```
<html><head></head><body>
    <div id="col1">
                <img id="img_frame" class="lazy-img" name="slide1">
            </div>
            <div id="col2">
                <img id="img_frame" class="lazy-img" name="slide2">
            </div>
            <div id="col3">
                <img id="img_frame" class="lazy-img" name="slide3">
            </div>
            <div id="col4">
                <img id="img_frame" class="lazy-img" name="slide4">
            </div>
            <div id="col5">
                <img id="img_frame" class="lazy-img" name="slide5">
            </div>    
    <script language="JavaScript1.1">
                function getImages() {
                    var slideimages = new Array();
                    slideimages = readfile();
                    if(slideimages){
                        slideit1()
                        slideit2()
                        slideit3()
                        slideit4()
                        slideit5()
                    }

                }

                function readfile(){ 
                    var allText =[];
                    var Lines = [];
                    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    txtFile.open("GET", "urls.txt", true);
                    allText = txtFile.responseText;
                    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function()
                    {
                        if (txtFile.readyState == 4 && txtFile.status == 200)
                        {// Makes sure it's found the file.
                            allText = txtFile.responseText;
                            Lines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
                        } 
                        else {
                            //alert("Didn't work"); 
                        }
                    }
                    txtFile.send(null)
                    return Lines
                }
                var slideshowspeed1=3000
                var slideshowspeed2=27000
                var slideshowspeed3=70000
                var slideshowspeed4=11000
                var slideshowspeed5=50000  

                var whichimage1=0
                var whichimage2=100
                var whichimage3=300
                var whichimage4=500
                var whichimage5=700



                function slideit1(){
                    if (!document.images)
                        return
                    document.images.slide1.src=slideimages[whichimage1]
                    if (whichimage1<slideimages.length-1)
                        whichimage1++
                    else
                        whichimage1=0
                    setTimeout("slideit1()",slideshowspeed1)}//slideit1()


                function slideit2(){
                    if (!document.images)
                        return
                    document.images.slide2.src=slideimages[whichimage2]
                    if (whichimage2<slideimages.length-1)
                    whichimage2++
                    else
                        whichimage2=0
                    setTimeout("slideit2()",slideshowspeed2)}//slideit2()

                function slideit3(){
                    if (!document.images)
                        return
                    document.images.slide3.src=slideimages[whichimage3]
                    if (whichimage3<slideimages.length-1)
                    whichimage3++
                    else
                        whichimage3=0
                    setTimeout("slideit3()",slideshowspeed3)}//slideit3()

                function slideit4(){
                    if (!document.images)
                        return
                    document.images.slide4.src=slideimages[whichimage4]
                    if (whichimage4<slideimages.length-1)
                    whichimage4++
                    else
                        whichimage4=0
                    setTimeout("slideit4()",slideshowspeed4)}//slideit4()

                function slideit5(){
                    if (!document.images)
                        return
                    document.images.slide5.src=slideimages[whichimage5]
                    if (whichimage5<slideimages.length-1)
                    whichimage5++
                    else
                        whichimage5=0
                    setTimeout("slideit5()",slideshowspeed5)}//slideit5()

            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really know why the divs on my webpage aren't displaying the images (whose urls are in the urls.txt file). I'm really new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be nesting functions like that. Every time you call readfile it will create a new readfile function object, which is bad design and can bog down your system if you're not careful. Also, you can really accomplish the same thing that "flag" is trying to accomplish in a much cleaner way. Try the following:

```
function getImages() {
  var slideimages = readfile();
  if (slideimages) {
    // execute slideshow functions
},

function readfile() {
  // read data into array x
  return x;
}
```

Your issue is probably with how you implemented "read data into array x." If you still cant figure it out, please post the rest of the code.

Comment: I've posted the rest of my code. could you please take a look and see if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong.